# Cohomology of the pullback of a coherent sheaf (considered as an abelian sheaf)

Tags: schemes, sheaf-cohomology, noetherian

Let $X$ be an affine Noetherian scheme, $Y$ a separated Noetherian scheme, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a morphism of schemes inducing a homeomorphism on the underlying topological spaces.

Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $Y$; treat it as a sheaf of abelian groups and pull it back to $X$. It is possible that $H^1(X, f^{-1}(F))\neq 0$?

This question may be confusing because we are essentially computing the sheaf cohomology of the exact same abelian sheaf on the exact same topological space but the non-trivial piece of information here is the existence of the morphism $f$ (remember, the forgetful functor from schemes to spaces is not full). Thus a random coherent sheaf on a separated scheme with non-vanishing $H^1$ is not going to do the trick.

Comment: I do not see the relevance of the "may be confusing" part here. If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism then $H^1(Y,F)\cong H^1(X,f^{-1}(F))$ for every sheaf $F$, coherent or not.

Comment: I don't see anything stopping us from taking $Y = X$ and $f = \mathrm{id}$. Then Certainly $H^1(X, f^{-1}\mathcal{F}) = H^1(X, \mathcal{F}) = 0$ since $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine scheme.

Comment: What's more relevant than the forgetful functor from schemes to spaces not being full is that the forgetful functor from quasi-coherent sheaves to sheaves of abelian groups is *exact*. So you can compute cohomology of a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ as the cohomology of the underlying sheaf of abelian groups.

Comment: @S.carmeli the question asked for an example where the cohomology of $f^{-1}(F)$ does not vanish. Do you have such an example?

Comment: @cgodfrey $f^{-1}(F)$ is not necessarily a quasi-coherent sheaf (the quasi-coherent sheaf is $f^{-1}(F)\otimes_{f^{-1}(O_Y)}O_X$). The question explicitly states that we are taking the pullback of an *abelian* sheaf. The cohomology of an arbitrary abelian sheaf on an affine Noetherian scheme does not necessarily vanish.

Comment: @StepanBanach The fact that the cohomology is unchanged by $f^{-1}$ together with the vanishing of the cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves on an affine variety together shows that there is no such example, $H^1(X,f^{-1}(F))$ always vanishes in this case. The fact that $f^{-1}(F)$ is not quasi-coherent has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @S.carmeli thak your for your comment. We start with a quasi-coherent sheaf on a possibly non-affine (but separated) scheme $Y$, pull it back to a possibly non-quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. It is true that the cohomology is not changed by pull-back. It is true that the cohomology of a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$ vanishes. How does it follow that the cohomology of $f^{-1}(F)$, which is the same as the cohomology of $F$, vanishes?

Comment: @StepanBanach Ohhh I see! I switched the role of the spaces (I had in mind that $X$ was non-affine but you written the opposite). Ill think about it this question seems to make much more sense when you read it appropriately.

Comment: @cgodfrey there is nothing stopping you, that is true, but the question asks about cases where the cohomology is *non-zero$, not zero. How is your comment relevant to the question?

Comment: @schematic_boi it's definitely not. I was confused and off base. My bad all!